# Interesting tags - add

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

It's possible to add a tag wrote in the "Interesting tags" input box, just pressing enter? Let me explain, I like the way one can select a tag from a drop-down list when you press the down key and having some text written. But the behavior of that textbox is inconsistent as you need to grab the mouse again and click the button "Add" to add the selected tag to the list. Can this action made when the user press the ENTER key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> is your friend.

After you've entered the tag, <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> across to the <kbd>Add</kbd> button and slam your interest with an almighty force on that <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

No touching of a mouse involved.

Comment: And the focus return to the textbox... great!